# How to share keyboard and mouse in Target Display Mode

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, target-display

Recently I've discovered an excellent software for MacOS, which provides an opportunity, among other things, to share the wireless keyboard and mouse between different computers. It is called [Teleport](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/18/how-to-use-teleport-to-share-a-keyboard-mouse-clipboard-between-different-macs/) and it works pretty neat.

The thing is that I'm trying to use this feature with iMac as target display and each time I'm switching off to target display mode cursor is lost on my macbook, and I just don't know what to do with this issue.

The question is - how can I share my mouse and keyboard in Target Display mode By phrase  "in target display mode" I mean tha if cursors has been teleported to macbook before switching to Target Display mode then it remains there after changing mode). With Teleport (preferable, since it is already in my private ecosystem) or without it.

**UPD:** Currently I'm just switching bluetooth on one device and switching it on on the other one. The only problem with this solution is that all my input devices are wireless, and thus I can not switch of bluetooth (MacOS just refuses to do that). So only for that purposes I've plugged in an USB mouse.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue using a Griffin PowerMate (basically, a USB-wired button) and some AppleScript to switch Bluetooth off on the iMac, freeing up the keyboard and mouse so my MacBook (connected via TDM) could take over.

It's very smooth (as smooth as can be for something non-standard). I just connect my MacBook to the iMac, hit cmd+F2 on the keyboard, then tap the button to disable Bluetooth and let the MacBook take charge. When I'm finished, I just unhook TDM, close the MacBook and tap the button again to reconnect the keyboard and mouse to the iMac's Bluetooth.

Details here - hope it's useful to someone else: http://jamesholland.com/post/80600076762/hacking-mac-os-x-to-toggle-bluetooth-for-better-target